# How to dynamically prevent Hibernate from updating cache on retrieval

Tags: hibernate

I have 'employee' records that are cached. The database contains way more employee records than are used on a day to day basis. However, my app provides a facility to 'export all' employees. On export all, I'd rather not have Hibernate add the retrieved records to the cache because the vast majority won't be useful in the cache. Adding all records to the cache would actually be a waste of resources (time spent adding to cache plus the fact it could cause older but more regularly accessed records to be flushed from the limited size cache).

I've read about javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode (BYPASS tells Hibernate to retrieve directly from the database) but does this also tell Hibernate to skip **updating** the cache? If not, is there some way to achieve this?

Note: My app actually uses Hibernate 3.6.4 so I suspect that using javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode may not be an option anyway. So any tips for achieveing the desired behaviour with this old version would be appreciated. But if the desired behaviour can only be achieved with the latest Hibernate then this may be just what I need to convince my manager that it's time to upgrade ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate's interaction with the 2nd level cache can be temporarily disabled by setting the cacheMode on the Session as follows:

```
CacheMode cacheMode = session.getCacheMode();  // Usually CacheMode.NORMAL
session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

// Execute the query
...

session.setCacheMode(cacheMode);  // Restore (best to do this in a finally block)
```